# Video / Screen Capture based testing tool?

Tags: uiautomation, coded-ui-tests

Does anyone know a good piece of software which software engineers / testers / etc can use to do either (1) manual testing or (2) automated testing?  It should have the ability to do a screen capture of their tests (either manually by starting/stoping capture OR automated via code/REST API).  Ideally the video could be uploaded to a youtube style repository (SaaS product or installed product) where they or other team members (e.g. testers, engineers, managers, etc) can log in and see videos of runs of previous tests.  Ideally videos could be marked for review so management / QA could mark `accepted` / `declined` which would result in the software going back to engineering and the cycle repeated.  Ideally for a test you could see the history via a series of videos.  Also, interested in screen capture for not only browser testers but also used for any UI based software.

Also, very interested if the screen video capture can be controlled by a REST API.

Bit of a brain dump there but does anyone know of a piece of software which can achieve this?

Comment: Great questions but unfortunately there are about 10+ questions here and this is actually more of a specification for your need than a question that will get suitable answers.  Suggest you break up the separate question - and search here and elsewhere because many of the individual questions have already been asked and have answers you could use.

Comment: Good advice Michael, will do.

Answer (score 1):

Jing, SnagIt are good for screenshots and videos.

Coded UI is good for making tickets to document test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SnagIt for screen capture and recording videos. You can upload all your screen captures and videos and provide link of the folder you have uploaded all your screen captures. Anyone with the link can view your screen captures.

Answer (score 0):

Try these out; they are very useful for manual testers to capture screenshots and videos.

1. [Jing](https://www.techsmith.com/jing-tool.html)
2. [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using "**Screencastify**" an extension provided by chrome browser where you can take videos in gif format.And for screen shot try using "**Full page screen capture**" an another chrome extension which is useful for taking screen shot of full page.

Answer (score 0):

Try [LICEcap](https://licecap.en.softonic.com/) - screen capture tool

Answer (score 0):

Selenium and Coded UI both allow capturing screenshots after each mouse click for every page or screen you are using for any web or native applications' UI. It can be done through coding.

Answer (score 0):

if you're operating on Linux

- for screen recording you might try [SimpleScreenRecorder](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/)
- for screen capturing you might try [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/downloads/)

Answer (score 0):

**Katalon Studio** can be used for manual, automatic, REST, SOAP, DB testing.

There is a recording tool included (**Katalon Recorder**).

You can set up the recording of failed or passed test cases, as a part of reporting capabilities for the web testing.

I guess you could then set up uploading of the recorded test cases, but you should use other tools to achieve this step.